# I am not be able to use DevicepolicyManger

Tags: android, eclipse, device-policy-manager

I can't able to use import `DevicepolicyManger` in my project. Look on below screenshot,

[image: i tried to import statement Import android.app.admin.DevicepolicyManager but i m not be able to use it]

Comment: What Android platform you are using?

Comment: i am using 2.1... thnx for asking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Api level is lower so raise this problem. use API level 8.  API 8 is Android 2.2 so you won't be able to use this on 2.1 or lower .

[image]

## Further more detail ::

Comment: mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        mDPM.lockNow();   but getting error plz help me

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/143a82414151e129

Comment: 10-11 16:36:49.935: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lock/com.lock.LockActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  ERROR like this